# How to show master / detail data in a single datagridview in c# win form apps

Tags: winforms, datagridview, .net-3.5, c#-2.0, multi-level

In Windows Application frameWork 3.5, in `DataGridView` control,
is it possible to show master detail records in a single datagridview, where plus sign will come and when click on plus then detail data will be shown (can expand/collaps).
please guide.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848637/Nested-DataGridView-in-windows-forms-csharp

Answer (score -1):

Is this any use?
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs

If not please explain specifics of why not and tag this question with the version of ASP you are using.

Comment: i am not talking about gridivew or asp.net......i am talking about datagridview which windows component.